# PHP - insert in prepared query doesn't work

Tags: php, sql, sqlite, sql-insert

I have hard time trying to do a simple insert into my sqlite3 db using php7.0

This code prints result correctly, so SELECT's work

```
$dbconn = new PDO('sqlite:/home/rooter/Desktop/XSS/db/ex1');
$stmtinit = $dbconn->prepare("select count() from tokens;");
$stmtinit->execute();

$rows = $stmtinit->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH);
$tks = $rows[0];
print "tokens_size:".$tks;
```

But code below doesn't do anything and doesn't throw any error/warning/notice. Table tokens has unchanged size.

```
$dbconn = new PDO('sqlite:/home/rooter/Desktop/XSS/db/ex1');
$stmt = $dbconn->prepare("insert into tokens(user, token) values ('plaintxt','plaintxt')");
$stmt->execute();
```

If i try to do that insert manually in db, it works properly.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php try that if you're not doing that already.

Comment: it's `count(*)` not `count()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following advice from Fred -ii- i turned error mode on

```
$dbconn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

Which resulted in message: *"attempt to write a readonly database"*. That happened because when I was creating database I was root.